# Shipping methods not displaying on front end

Tags: expresso-store

Seen the posts about a similar issue with Fedex, though in this case there's not fedex api/plugin.

I have 2 shipping methods. Both enabled in the backend.

I have tried spitting them other a couple of ways,

```
{shipping_methods}
    <option value="{method_id}">{method_title}</option>
{/shipping_methods}
```

&

```
{shipping_method_options}
```

Also this doesn't display anything:

```
{error:shipping_method}
```

I'm within a store checkout tag:

```
{exp:store:checkout require="name|address1|state|country|postcode" return="/review-and-pay" form_class="form"}
```

Comment: Can you add what shipping methods you are trying to use and your full template code?

Comment: Just some standard ones with not a lot of stuff in really. Seems to work ok now, I think I just cleared my session and created a new order and they showed up!

Comment: Found it. I was being dumb. Set country code to "uk" on a hidden field not the actual country code that is set for the United Kingdom in the backend is "GB".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I was being dumb. Set country code to "uk" on a hidden field not the actual country code that is set for the United Kingdom in the backend is "GB".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your shipping method, sometimes it won't display any results until the zip code has been submitted. So in order to pull those shipping methods, you would need to submit via ajax, or break your checkout into separate pages.

Comment: Seems to work ok now, I think I just cleared my session and created a new order and they showed up!

Comment: Seems that I spoke too soon :| this has happened again. Though I've tried your method of putting it on another checkout step (after postcode has been taken). Yet still I get a blank select :(

Comment: How are you submitting your state and country codes? If these don't match the api's call method, it will silently fail and not give you any results.

Comment: Found it. I was being dumb. Set country code to "uk" on a hidden field not the actual country code that is set for the United Kingdom in the backend is "GB".